# How to disable the lightning debug popups

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, debugging

How to disable the lightning debug popups

We are having this popups on a salesforce standard lightning components in a **Sandbox Summer 17 (Preview)**

I disabled debug mode in the Configuration -> Lightning components but the popup still displays

[image: Debug]

Comment: There is something badly wrong with your page. You can't turn this off. Fix the error and the popup will go away.